# How to strip each array of the square brackets and add a prefix

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe with the top 12 predictions my kNN has made for each ID, it looks like this:

| customer_id | prediction |
| --- | --- |
| 00000dbacae5abe5e2 | [677530001, 677515001, 677511001, 677506003, 677501001, 677490001, 677478006, 677478003, 677478002, 677546006, 949551001, 903049003] |
| 0000423b00ade9141 | [677511001, 677506003, 677501001, 677490001, 677478006, 677478003, 677478002, 677386001, 677385001, 677760003, 949551001, 826674001] |

Is it possible to remove the square brackets from each line (they are arrays) in the dataframe and also add a prefix of zero before each prediction, like this:

| customer_id | prediction |
| --- | --- |
| 00000dbacae5abe5e2 | 0677530001, 0677515001, 0677511001..... |
| 0000423b00ade9141 | 0677511001, 0677506003, 0677501001..... |

My code in generating these predictions and tables:

```
n = 12
probas = kNN.predict_proba(X.head())
top_n_idx = np.argsort(probas, axis=1)[:,-n:]
top_n = [kNN.classes_[i] for i in top_n_idx]
results = list(zip(top_n))

results = pd.DataFrame(results)
ids_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
results.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
y_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
knn_table = pd.concat([ids, results], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
knn_table = knn_table.rename(columns={0: 'customer_id', 1: 'prediction'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df["prediction"] = ("0"+df["prediction"].explode().astype(str)).groupby(level=0).agg(", ".join)
```

Alternatively with `apply`:

```
df["prediction"] = df["prediction"].apply(lambda x: "0"+", 0".join(map(str,x)))
```

###### Output:

```
>>> df

          customer_id                                         prediction
0  00000dbacae5abe5e2  0677530001, 0677515001, 0677511001, 0677506003...
1   0000423b00ade9141  0677511001, 0677506003, 0677501001, 0677490001...
```